# Interactive querying of java heap dumps in headless (terminal only) machine

Tags: java, heap-dump, eclipse-mat

I need to investigate a potential memory leak in a java application.

specifically: I have an object type that is contained in a map. this data is reread every now and then, and the map is replaced with the new one.
However, it appears that some of the old objects aren't always released, even after forcing gc externally.

I started using MAT with the predefined reports (leak suspects, etc.) but I need to further dig in.

Using the GUI version of mat is impractical, as the machine is a remote linux server (I tried MAT with X11 and it wasn't responsive, and the dumps are to large to download)

I'm looking for a method to further analyze the heap dump using command line tools.

There are several related questions in SO and other sites - but I didn't find anything beyond the options I tried (using predefined reports)

Comment: Are dumps really so large? Can't you just take dump on your remote server with something like `jmap -dump:format=b,file=mydump.bin <pid>` and then download it (a couple of Gb's I suppose) to your dev machine and analyze with MAT?

Comment: There is also jhat tool - maybe it will help you http://petermodzelewski.blogspot.ru/2013/06/short-jhat-tutorial-diagnosing.html